# How to make /fill and /setblock output not show up in the chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When using `/fill` or `/setblock` commands to place a redstone block, the message "Successfully filled 1 block" appears in the chat. I would like to prevent this message from appearing.

I tried `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false` but it does not work. Is there a fix?

If it matters, I am playing on a server.

Answer (score 5):

## Wrong Gamerule

You should be running the command:

```
/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false
```

## Also

You can also run:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

to make command block commands not appear in chat.